# How to using c # on linux to create folder?

Tags: c#, linux

I have developed a tool using C# (visual studio 2012) in windows,where i have used `FileSystemWatcher`.

```
private FileSystemWatcher m_file_watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(filewatch_path);
```

where

```
filewatch_path = C:\\mytool\\INBOX
```

`FileSystemWatcher`  checks folder C:\mytool\INBOX . When the file in added in 
C:\mytool\INBOX folder, the tool works accordingly.

Now i have install this tool in Linux system. I am not sure how this will work because the folder i want to keep a watch is `"/INBOX"` .

> (the user root directory is "/" and the correct path is  "/INBOX".)

SO do you think if i will change the `filewatch_path = C:\\mytool\\INBOX` to `filewatch_path = \INBOX`, will this work ?

I cannot test this becuase i dont have Linux system.

Also if i want to create more folder in the root directory can i just write the below code to create folder.

```
string path = @"\LOG";
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Thanks for Helping me.

Prat

Comment: I suggest you download a virtual machine, for example VirtualBox and install linux on it to test

Comment: Yes download the VM and try it you can use Wine to run windows apps on linux because natively it is not possible to run windows apps on linux

Comment: Don't use wine....
.NET Apps can be run natively on linux if you have mono installed.

Comment: RTM: `Directory.CreateDirectory` will only create a directory if one does not exist already.

Comment: Thanks Guys , Dowloading virtual box and install linux is best way to test the things myself. But i have to deply my tool quickly , so i posted my question here.

Comment: @leppie : i know that, will it make the folder in root Directory in the Linux.

Comment: Your design itself is questionable even on Windows. How can you guarantee that your app has read permissions on that path and how does it create this directory of it does not exist? On Linux, except the file system structure is different, you still face the same permission challenge.

Comment: @LexLi : Everything is fine on windows ,all the permission is taken care off. I just want to know about Linux. What should i do to read a file form from `\INBOX` also how to create folders in Root Directory.

Comment: @Kha : Thanks Kha.I not worried about the permission because that can be handled easily. I just need the confirmation that `Directory.CreateDirectory("/inbox")` will create a folder in root Directory, which you gave. Thanks again.
Can you please also confirm that `private FileSystemWatcher m_file_watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("/inbox");` will also work.

Comment: Use `/` which should work on both. Example would be `Directory.CreateDirectory("/inbox");`. On windows, it will create one in the root folder (`c:\` for me) and in linux, granted you have root permission, it will create an `/inbox` directory.

Comment: @GameBuilder I don't know about the file watcher. In theory it should work but in practice, I've never used `FileWatcher` in Linux and instead used `incron` and native shell scripts to implement file watchers in linux (i.e. not with any programming language). The only thing i can recommend is to run it under a VM (or better yet, on an actual machine with the distro you're testing against) and see if it works. Remember, `FileWatcher` is dodgy even on windows :).